# need only last character of a long string c++

Tags: c++, character

I am using c++ and the judge get me a long long string (that it cant be in string) .
I need only two last characters ! What should i do ?? Don't forget that this code don't answer correctly !

```
char a,b;
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
a=s[s.size()-1];
b=s[s.size()-2];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::cin >> s;
```

This tokenizes the input on whitespace characters. I.e., if `Long John Silver` waits in standard input, you'll only get `Long` in `s`. Do it in a loop

```
while (std::cin >> s) ;
```

or use `std::getline(std::cin, s);` instead (if input can contain newline characters, the same applies - do it in a loop then).

Comment: when will it go out of while ?

Comment: but if i want to input in my code , it inputs for ever !

Comment: i want something that get input like cin but take only two last characters .

Comment: If you're doing input manualy, you need to insert EOF by yourself (CTRL+Z on windows, CTRL+D on unix').

Answer (score 0):

this function safely returns the last 2 characters of any string, unless there are fewer than 2 characters in the string, in which case it returns all available characters:

```
std::string last_2(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::string(std::prev(s.end(), 2), 
                       s.end());
}
```

so does this:

```
std::string last_2(const std::string& s)
{
    return s.substr(std::max(s.length(),std::size_t(2))-2, 2);
}
```